# How to deal with dates from Forms to Spreadsheets using Google Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script, invalid-argument

I have a Google Script that takes the input of a date of a Google Form field and I want to save the day, month and year separately. In particular, I want to change the month number to text i.e. `03` means `March`. That's why I use `substring`.

- Format of Date in Google Forms: `dd/mm/yyyy`.
- Format of Date in Google Spreadsheets: `d/mm/yyyy` if `day<10` and `dd/mm/yyyy` if `day>=10`.

The critical part is here:

```
const cDay = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(0,2);
var cMonth = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(3,5);
const cYear = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(6,10);
```

If the user submits a day less than 10, then the code is broken.

How can we solve this problem **not changing the format on the Google Spreadsheets file?**

I couldn't find a way using `if` or `switch` statements.

### More explanation

I tried with this code:

```
var cDay;
var cMonth;
var cYear;
if (e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(1,2) == '/') { // Days are 1,..,9
  cDay = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(0,1);
  cMonth = changeMonth(e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(2,4));
  cYear = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(5,9);
} else { // Days are 10,..,31
  cDay = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(0,2);
  cMonth = changeMonth(e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(3,5));
  cYear = e.namedValues['Date'][0].substring(6,10);
}
```

Function `changeMonth`:

```
function changeMonth(month) {
  switch (month) {
    case '01':
    case '1':
      cMonth = 'January';
      break;
    case '02':
    case '2':
      cMonth = 'February';
      break;
    case '03':
    case '3':
      cMonth = 'March';
      break;
    case '04':
    case '4':
      cMonth = 'April';
      break;
    case '05':
    case '5':
      cMonth = 'May';
      break;
    case '06':
    case '6':
      cMonth = 'June';
      break;
    case '07':
    case '7':
      cMonth = 'July';
      break;
    case '08':
    case '8':
      cMonth = 'August';
      break;
    case '09':
    case '9':
      cMonth = 'September';
      break;
    case '10':
      cMonth = 'October';
      break;
    case '11':
      cMonth = 'November';
      break;
    case '12':
      cMonth = 'December';
      break;
  }
}
```

It seems the error occurs when I use `replaceText`:

```
body.replaceText('<<Day>>', cDay);
body.replaceText('<<Month>>', cMonth); // I get "Invalid argument: replacement"
body.replaceText('<<Year>>', cYear);
```

I found that a solution is to add `String(...)` to the parameters of `replaceText` so I have: `body.replaceText(String('<<Month>>'), String(cMonth));`.

However, when I see the results I get the correct day and year but the month is `undefined`. What can we do?

### Example

If the user submits `03/05/2000` on Forms, the output has to be: `You have submitted the form on the 3º day of the month of May of the year 2000`. Instead I have `You have submitted the form on the 3º day of the month of undefined of the year 2000`.

Comment: If you know a proper function that takes the day, month and year of a date field in Google Forms, please let me know. That would be much more simpler.

Comment: You could split on forward slashes and the parseInt() every element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the dates by yourself, you could use the JavaScript **Date** object to get the day, month and year.

***Note**: this solution is applicable if the format of date is dd/mm/yyyy*

**Try this:**

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  var dateStr = e.namedValues["Date"][0];
  var dateArr = dateStr.split("/");
  var newDate = dateArr[1]+"/"+dateArr[0]+"/"+dateArr[2];
  var date = new Date(newDate);
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  Logger.log("You have submitted the form on the "+day+"º day of the month of "+monthNames[month]+" of the year "+year)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I realized that in the Form the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, but I get it as `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want it as `dd/mm/yyyy`. How to solve this?

Comment: Does it produce incorrect output? Upon checking Brock Harrison answer [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3080777?hl=en&msgid=8218053) date format  is linked to the Language setting of your profile. Thus, changing the language will change the date format.

Comment: Yes it produces incorrect output, because the days are the months and viceversa. So the array of months can have up to 31 slots, which causes an exception. Is there any way to not change the Language setting of my profile but solve the issue?

Comment: The easiest solution is to split the date string and swap the position of date and month. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!! It works on a sample Form. I will try in the real Form, but I suspect it would be the same output.

Comment: I am having a new problem, actually I have a lot of fields named Date (1), Date (2), Date (3), Date (4), Date (5) and Date (6), where each of them is a Date field. How can I create arrays instead of a single variable named `var date=new Date(newDate);`? I also need to separate day, month and year and put to a Google Docs template. I have tried the following: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51918642#51918642  Instead of receiving the day, month, year of Date 1, day, month, year of Date 2 etc I receive `NaN` for each field. How to solve this?

Comment: @manooooh - I would like to support you but the issue is different from your post above. Kindly create another post regarding your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMDY(input="01/04/2021") {
  const a=['Day','Month','Year'];
  Logger.log(input.split('/').map((e,i)=>{ return a[i] + ": " + parseInt(e)}).join('\r\n'));
}

Execution log
12:38:40 PM Notice  Execution started
12:38:40 PM Info    
Day: 1
Month: 4
Year: 2021
12:38:40 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!